# No puedo instalar 'loadR' (climate4R) en R

Tags: r

Estoy usando windows 10 y R version 4.0.2. He intentado con ubuntu 20 (Fossa), pero el problema es el mismo. Tambien con otras versiones de R (3.6.1 y 3.6.3).

El mensaje del error es el siguiente:

```
* installing *source* package 'loadeR' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: package 'climate4R.UDG' 0.1.1 was found, but >= 0.2.0 is required by 'loadeR'
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'loadeR'
```

Cual podría ser la solución?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, traduce tu pregunta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De forma temporal, por favor intenta instalar `climate4R.UDG` desde la rama de desarrollo. Por ejemplo:

`devtools::install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG@devel, "SantanderMetGroup/loadeR")`

En breve volverá a la normalidad. Espero que sirva de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias Joaquín

Comment: Espero no le moleste que coloque su respuesta en stackoverflow en ingles, pues ahí me han dado otras alternativas que no fueron la solución.